# The use of law of total variance, when probability space is not the same

Tags: probability-theory, variance

The problem is as follows:

1. The population $X$ of 100 samples is drawn from standard normal distribution.
2. Then from $X$ 50 samples (let's call them $\widetilde{X}$) are drawn uniformly with replacement.
3. The mean of $\widetilde{X}$ is calculated (let's call it $\overline{\widetilde{X}}$).

I need to derive variance of $\overline{\widetilde{X}}$.

I used [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), which states:

$$Var[Y] = E[Var[Y|X]] + Var[E[Y|X]]$$

In my case, this translated to:

$$Var[\overline{\widetilde{X}}] = E[Var[\overline{\widetilde{X}} | X]] + Var[E[\overline{\widetilde{X}} | X]]$$

I derived $Var[\overline{\widetilde{X}} | X]$ and $E[\overline{\widetilde{X}} | X]$ as though $X$ is a known general population, getting new random variables, and then derived their expected value and variance accordingly. The result was the value $$\frac{1}{50} \frac{99}{100} + \frac{1}{100} = 0.0298$$

The question is, am I doing something wrong and is this even legal? Wikipedia states that law of total variance applies only if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables **on the same probability space**, but that does not seem to hold in this case. But the derived result was consistent with experiments I did, just generating a lot of values following the algorithm above and then calculating their empirical variance.

Comment: why do you think "that does not seem to hold in this case"?

Comment: You are asking for the variance of $$Z=\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_{I(k)}$$ where $(I(k))$ is i.i.d. uniform on $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, $(X_i)$ is i.i.d. standard normal, and the families $(I(k))$ and $(X_i)$ are independent. Note that, for every $k$, $E(X_{I(k)})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^NE(X_i\mid I(k)=i)P(I(k)=i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^NE(X_i)\frac1N=0$, thus $E(Z)=0$. Likewise, for every $k$, $E(X_{I(k)}^2)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^NE(X_i^2\mid I(k)=i)P(I(k)=i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^NE(X_i^2)\frac1N=1$. Using similar decompositions and shortening somewhat the computations, ...

Comment: ... one also has, for every $k\ne\ell$, $E(X_{I(k)}X_{I(\ell)})=E(X_1^2)P(I(k)=I(\ell))+E(X_1)^2P(I(k)\ne I(\ell))=\frac1N$. Putting all these together, one sees that $n^2E(Z^2)=nE(X_{I(1)}^2)+n(n-1)E(X_{I(1)}X_{I(2)})=n+n(n-1)\frac1N$ and, finally, that $$\mathrm{var}(Z)=\frac1n+\frac{n-1}n\frac1N.$$

Comment: (Every random variable involved is defined on the same probability space, of course.)

Comment: @snarfblaat Well, $X$ is 100-dimensional, and $\overline{\widetilde{X}}$ is 1-dimensional. The probability space is defined as a triple of sample space, a set of events and the probability function, and the sample space here is not the same. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Did $E(X_{I(k)}) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} E(X_i | I(k) = i) P(I(k) = i)$ -- what is this formula?

Comment: @Alex "what is this formula?" You can call it "Bayes formula" if you want, or pure logic... The events $A_i=[I(k)=i]$ partition the sample space $\Omega$ hence $E(U)=\sum\limits_iE(U;A_i)$ for every integrable random variable $U$. Now, if $U=X_{I(k)}$, then $U=X_i$ on $A_i$ hence $E(U;A_i)=E(X_i;A_i)=E(X_i\mid A_i)P(A_i)$ for each $i$ hence the formula in your comment.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the breakdown.